# PHP won't echo the correct date

Tags: php

```
/* yeardate = 2000 monthdate = 02 daydate = 02 */
$date = new DateTime($yeardate.'-'.$monthdate.'-'.$daydate);
echo date('Y/m/d', strtotime($date));
```

Keeps echoing 1970/01/01 or something on the lines of that.

Comment: You don't need DateTime object just put your date inside strtotime. echo date('Y/m/d', strtotime($yeardate.'/'.$monthdate.'/'.$daydate));

Comment: simple: `echo date('Y-m-d');`

Comment: Try this: `$date = '2000-02-02';
echo date('Y/m/d', strtotime($date));`

Comment: Thank you for the reply! but is there anyway I can use variables instead?

Comment: echo date('Y/m/d', strtotime($yeardate.'-'.$monthdate.'-'.$daydate));

Answer (score 1):

here you are, try to use proper class like below:

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2000-02-02');
echo $date->format('Y/m/d');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use php date function,

```
echo date('Y-m-d');
```